# Perform calculations before recording in the archive

Tags: yii2

What better way to carry out an operation between two fields and save result to a third column? Must be made `actionCreate` or `beforeSave`?

**Columns:**

- `Value` (user input)
- `commission` (user input)
- `companys_revenue` (just a field)

Example:

```
value x commission = companys_revenue
```

I need to get the data that the user entered and apply the formula and write to the database

Comment: Why are you storing a calculated value like this in the database? Why not just calculate it when you retrieve the record?  Or is the value likely to be changed by some future process?

Comment: this value can change periodically. Example commission in 2014 10% 20% 15%, commission in 2015 to 25%

Comment: Ah, ok I see. So is the value for company_revenue only to be calculated for new records, at the time of creation? If you force a calculation in the beforeSave( event then it will recalculate every time the record is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did as follows:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if ($this->isNewRecord)
    {
        $companys_revenue = ($this->value*$this->commission_percent)/100;
        $this->companys_revenue = abs($companys_revenue);

    }
        $companys_revenue = ($this->value*$this->commission_percent)/100;
        $this->companys_revenue = abs($companys_revenue);

    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a controller :

```
public function actionCalculation() {
$model = new classname();
if(Yii::$app->request->post()['calculationform']){
   $value = Yii::$app->request->post()['calculationform']['value'];
   $comission = Yii::$app->request->post()['calculationform']['comission'];
   $revenue= Yii::$app->request->post()['calculationform']['revenue'];
     $calulation = $model->getFormula($value,$comission,$revenue);
 $model->calulation = $calulation;
 $model->save();
$this->render('your code');
}
```

in calculation class :

```
public $value,$revenue,$comission;

public function getFormula($value,$comission,$revenue){
your calulation write here.....;
}
    }
```

in this way you applied your formula and save that calculation in your database.There is another way also , but try to write logic in model .
i just show you the example you need to take care of the code and other logic also.